# select documents with sub arrays that match some critieria

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections with documents such as:

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  _class: "com.acme.classA",
  a_collection: [    
    {
      otherdata: 'somedata',
      type: 'a'
    },
    {
      otherdata: 'bar',
      type: 'a'
    },
    {
      otherdata: 'foo',
      type: 'b'
    }
  ],
  lastChange: ISODate("2014-08-17T22:25:48.918Z")
}
```

I want to find all document by id and a subset of the sub array. for example I want to find all documents with id "1234" and a_collection.type is 'a' giving this result:

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  _class: "com.acme.classA",
  a_collection: [    
    {
      otherdata: 'somedata',
      type: 'a'
    },
    {
      otherdata: 'bar',
      type: 'a'
    }
  ],
  lastChange: ISODate("2014-08-17T22:25:48.918Z")
}
```

I have tried this :

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
    $match: {
        'a_collection.type': 'a'
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$a_collection"
},
{
    $match: {
        "a_collection.type": 'a'
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        a_collection: {
            $addToSet: "$a_collection"
        },

    }
}).pretty()
```

but this doesnt return other properties ( such as 'lastChange' )
what is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP?

And is this the only way you can get the "text"?

maybe you can rewrite it that it is like an JSON element.

something like that:

```
 {
  "_id": "1234",
  "_class": "com.acme.classA",
  "a_collection": [    
    {
      "otherdata": "somedata",
      "type": "a"
    },
    {
      "otherdata": "bar",
      "type": "a"
    },
    {
      "otherdata": "foo",
      "type": "b"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can use the json_decode() function from PHP to make an array and then you can search and return only the needed data.

**Edit: I read read false. do you search for a funktion like this?**

```
  db.inventory.find(    {
         $or: [ { _id: "1234" }, { 'a_collection.type': 'a' }] 
   } )
```

[Here][1] I found the code ;)   [1]: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Comment: I need a to know how to query mongodb regardless to the client

Comment: this doesnt help it will return the original document with all of the sub items ( including type: 'b' )

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct query:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
    $match: {
        'a_collection.type': 'a'
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$a_collection"
},
{
    $match: {
        "a_collection.type": 'a'
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        a_collection: {
            $addToSet: "$a_collection"
        },
        lastChange : { $first : "$lastChange" }

    }
}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is very strange about your desired query (and your pipelines). First of all, `_id` is a reserved field with a unique index on it. The result of finding all documents with `_id = "1234"` can only be 0 or 1 documents. Second, to find documents with `a_collection.type = "a"` for some element of the array `a_collection`, you don't need the aggregation framework. You just need a find query:

```
> db.test.find({ "a_collection.type" : "a" })
```

So all the work here appears to be winnowing the subarray of one document down to just those elements with `a_collection.type = "a"`. Why do you have these objects in the same document if most of what you do is split them up and eliminate some to find a result set? How common and how truly necessary is it to harvest just the array elements with `a_collection.type = "a"`? Perhaps you want to model your data differently so a query like

```
> db.test.find({ <some condition>, "a_collection.type" : "a" })
```

returns you the correct documents. I can't say how you can do it best with the given information, but I can say that your current approach strongly suggests revision is needed (and I'm happy to help with suggestions if you include further information or post a new question).

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer, I am actually rethinking my current approach, I will try to explain my situation and what I did.
You are correct that my query will always return only one document, the intention is only to filter out sub elements in that document. my document represents some client data, each client has one and only one document in the collection, but many data elements as a sub array. the client data updates periodically and what I do is just save the new document and by that replacing all the client old data with the new data.

Comment: I realize that a different approach would be to use a separate document for every data node for every client, and that would give me a collection that includes many documents for each client, but then whenever I want to update the clients data I have to first delete all the clients documents and save the new ones. I realize that with this approach it would be much easier to query the data, but wont it be less efficient when updating .
This is my first attempts with non relational database that's why I am not used to these kind of dilemmas, any help would be great :)

Comment: The first questions to ask in [data modeling with MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) is "what do my typical queries look like, i.e. what is the question(s) I'm trying to answer most often or with highest priority? What do updates or changes look like? What is the balance of amount and frequency of queries versus updates? You use these questions to design a data model that makes your common operations easy and fast. I'm happy to help work through some of these questions with you, but if you'd like to please make another question since it's a whole new and larger topic.

Comment: I can try and explain my data model, but I am not sure a so question would fit for that, is there a mail I can contact you with ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the answer you have submitted yourself, but for that in MongoDB 2.6 and greater there is a better way to do this with  [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/). Which wer both introduced at that version. But where available, this is much faster in the approach:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "a_collection.type": "a" } },
    { "$project": {
        "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": [
                "input": "$a_collection",
                 "as": "el",
                 "in": {
                     "$cond": [
                         { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "a" ] },
                         "$$el", 
                         false
                     ]
                 }
            ]},
            [false]
        ]
    }}
])
```

So that has no "group" or initial "unwind" which both can be costly options, along with the **`$match`** stage. So MongoDB 2.6 does it better.